# Return true if user input matches to predefined string

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

I working on search function for projects. I have multiple projects with different titles, description and types. What I need is that the function returns true if the project title, description or type contains characters/words from the user input.

E.g.

We have 3 projects:

1. title = 'foo 1', projectType = 'good', description = 'good description'
2. title = 'bar 1', projectType = 'bad', description = 'this is description',
3. title = 'foo bar', projectType = 'neutral', description = 'this is something',

User input is 'foo', returns true for 1. and 3.
User input is 'foo this is', return true for 1. 2. and 3.

I have so far created following function

```
checkProjectStrings(project: ProjectEntity, filterText: string) {
        let containTextTitle: boolean | undefined;
        let containsTextDescription: boolean | undefined;
        let containsTextType: boolean | undefined;

        const filterTextArray = filterText.split(' ');

        filterTextArray.map(filterTextString => {
            if (project.title != undefined) {
                containTextTitle = project.title.toLowerCase().includes(filterTextString.toLowerCase());
            }
            if (project.description != undefined) {
                containsTextDescription = project.description.toLowerCase().includes(filterTextString.toLowerCase());
            }
            if (project.projectType != undefined) {
                containsTextType = project.projectType.toLowerCase().includes(filterTextString.toLowerCase());
            }
        })

        if (containTextTitle || containsTextDescription || containsTextType) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The problem in my function seems that it is always working just with the last string provided

Comment: because you override containTextTitle, containsTextDescription, containsTextType on every iteration. Not sure why you are using map when you do not use it as map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code overrides your variables on every iteration. You would need to alter your ifs to not run it if there is a match

```
if (project.title != undefined && !containTextTitle ) { ... }
```

You can simply it with some

```
const filterTextArray = filterText.split(' ');

filterTextArray.some(filterTextString => {
  return (project.title && project.title.toLowerCase().includes(filterTextString.toLowerCase())) || (project.description &&
    containsTextDescription = project.description.toLowerCase().includes(filterTextString.toLowerCase())
  ) ||
  (project.projectType &&
    project.projectType.toLowerCase().includes(filterTextString.toLowerCase())
  )
})
```

Comment: There is typo in your answer but otherwise it does what I need. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it by turning the entire project object into a single string line

```js
const projectsContainingInput = projects
      .filter( project => {
        const projectLine = Object.values(project).join(' ').toLowerCase() // ex. 'facebook social media'
        return words.some(word => projectLine.includes(word))
      })
```

https://codepen.io/chevallm/pen/qBEpoVg